# Get Sum and sum of last 24 hours in a single query in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to get total sum and sum of last day and count also in single query,

here the sample data.

```
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | transfer_amount | addedon             |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      50000.0000 | 2020-02-20 10:51:12 |
|  2 |       2000.0000 | 2020-02-20 10:52:57 |
|  3 |      10000.0000 | 2020-02-17 10:53:37 |
|  4 |       7000.0000 | 2020-02-17 10:54:28 |
|  5 |        500.0000 | 2020-02-17 10:55:07 |
| 23 |       1000.0000 | 2020-02-19 17:37:06 |
| 24 |       1000.0000 | 2020-02-19 17:41:12 |
| 25 |       1000.0000 | 2020-02-19 17:46:48 |
| 26 |       1000.0000 | 2020-02-19 17:47:17 |
| 30 |       1000.0000 | 2020-02-19 17:58:38 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
```

i tried to given query ,

```
select SUM(amount) as total_amount, COUNT('ALL') as total_count, 
    (select SUM(amount) from `transfers`WHERE date > '2021-01-04 23:59:59' AND 
      date <= '2021-01-05 23:59:59') as last_day_sum
from `transfers`;
```

and result

```
+----------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| total_amount   | total_count | last_day_sum | last_day_count |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| 314286380.0000 |       88452 |    1200.0000 |        0       |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
```

any other options for this ?

Comment: `WHERE date > '2021-01-04 23:59:59' AND date <= '2021-01-05 23:59:59'` There is no column called `date`. And even if there was, you would have to put backticks around it because `date` is a reserved word.

Comment: @kmoser date is not a reserved word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this query

```
select SUM(amount) as total_amount, COUNT('ALL') as total_count, 
    SUM(case when date > '2021-01-04 23:59:59' AND 
      date <= '2021-01-05 23:59:59' then amount else 0 end) as last_day_sum
from `transfers`;
```

**Update** for last day count

```
select SUM(amount) as total_amount, COUNT('ALL') as total_count, 
   SUM(case when date > '2021-01-04 23:59:59' AND 
      date <= '2021-01-05 23:59:59' then amount else 0 end) as last_day_sum, 
   SUM(date > '2021-01-04 23:59:59' AND 
      date <= '2021-01-05 23:59:59') as last_day_count
from `transfers`;
```

**Shorter code**

```
select sum(transfer_amount) as total_amount, count(*) as total_count, 
   sum(if(date(`date`) = '2021-01-05', transfer_amount, 0)) as last_day_sum, 
   sum(date(`date`) = '2021-01-05') as last_day_count
from `transfers`;
```

Comment: is this correct for count also ,

`select SUM(amount) as total_amount, COUNT('ALL') as total_count,  SUM(case when date > '2021-01-04 23:59:59' AND  date <= '2021-01-05 23:59:59' then amount else 0 end) as last_day_sum,
       COUNT(case when date > '2021-01-04 23:59:59' AND date <= '2021-01-05 23:59:59' then amount else 0 end) as last_day_count
         from `transfers`;`

Comment: yes, you can also shorter anyway, see in answer

Comment: last day count getting total count only.

Comment: @noushidp it should work fine, check your conditions.
FYI see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daabea/8

Comment: '@girish' in this table have more than 10 lakh record,so query will too slow,
how can reduce the query execution time.column indexes are there already.

Comment: this query is checking all records in table, that would be slow with large records, but you can create a new table to store aggregated data and keep updated new table timely by background job.

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(transfer_amount) as total_amount, COUNT(*) as total_count, 
    (select ifnull(SUM(transfer_amount),0) from transfers WHERE date(addedon) = '2020-02-19') as last_day_sum
from transfers;
```

You ll have to convert the date string to date type.
Also, since you just need the date, you can reduce it to the one above instead of `where x and y`.
This will give the sum and sum of last 24 hours in the same query.

Comment: column name is dummy i need logic,

Comment: made the changes. please check. Your dummy data and query didnt have any data between the dat range, so returned so.